# Calculation of application speedup using gnuplot and awk

Tags: performance, awk, gnuplot

Here's the problem:

Speedup formula: S(p) = T(1)/T(p) = (avg time for one process / avg time for *p* processes)

There are 5 logs, from which one wants to extract the information.
cg.B.1.log contains the execution times for one process, so we do the calculation of the average time to obtain T(1). The other log files contain the execution times for 2, 4, 8 and 16 processes. Averages of those times must also be calculated, since they are T(p).

Here's the code that calculates the averages:

```
tavg(n) = "awk 'BEGIN { FS = \"[ \\t]*=[ \\t]*\" }  /Time in seconds/ { s += $2; c++ } /Total processes/ { if (! CP) CP = $2 } END { print s/c }' cg.B.".n.".log ".(n == 1 ? ">" : ">>")." tavg.dat;"
```

And the code that calculates the speedup:

```
system "awk 'NR==1{n=$0} {print n/$0}' tavg.dat > speedup.dat;"
```

How do I combine those two commands so that the output 'speedup.dat' is produced directly without using file *tavg.dat*?

Here are the contents of files, the structure of all log files is identical. I attached only the first two executions for abbreviation purposes.

**cg.B.1.log**

```
-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-
Start in 16:45:15--25/12/2014


 NAS Parallel Benchmarks 3.3 -- CG Benchmark

 Size:      75000
 Iterations:    75
 Number of active processes:     1
 Number of nonzeroes per row:       13
 Eigenvalue shift: .600E+02

   iteration           ||r||                 zeta
    1       0.30354859861452E-12    59.9994751578754
    2       0.11186435488267E-14    21.7627846142536
    3       0.11312258511928E-14    22.2876617043224
    4       0.11222160585284E-14    22.5230738188346
    5       0.11244234177219E-14    22.6275390653892
    6       0.11330434819384E-14    22.6740259189533
    7       0.11334259623050E-14    22.6949056826251
    8       0.11374839313647E-14    22.7044023166872
    9       0.11424877443039E-14    22.7087834345620
   10       0.11329475190566E-14    22.7108351397177
   11       0.11337364093482E-14    22.7118107121341
   12       0.11379928308864E-14    22.7122816240971
   13       0.11369453681794E-14    22.7125122663243
   14       0.11430390337015E-14    22.7126268007594
   15       0.11400318886400E-14    22.7126844161819
   16       0.11352091331197E-14    22.7127137461755
   17       0.11350923439124E-14    22.7127288402000
   18       0.11475378864565E-14    22.7127366848296
   19       0.11366777929028E-14    22.7127407981217
   20       0.11274243312504E-14    22.7127429721364
   21       0.11353930792856E-14    22.7127441294025
   22       0.11299685800278E-14    22.7127447493900
   23       0.11296405041170E-14    22.7127450834533
   24       0.11381975597887E-14    22.7127452643881
   25       0.11328127301663E-14    22.7127453628451
   26       0.11367332658939E-14    22.7127454166517
   27       0.11283372178605E-14    22.7127454461696
   28       0.11384734158863E-14    22.7127454624211
   29       0.11394011989719E-14    22.7127454713974
   30       0.11354294067640E-14    22.7127454763703
   31       0.11412988029103E-14    22.7127454791343
   32       0.11358088407717E-14    22.7127454806740
   33       0.11263266152515E-14    22.7127454815316
   34       0.11275183080286E-14    22.7127454820131
   35       0.11328306951409E-14    22.7127454822840
   36       0.11357880314891E-14    22.7127454824349
   37       0.11332687790488E-14    22.7127454825202
   38       0.11324108818137E-14    22.7127454825684
   39       0.11365065523777E-14    22.7127454825967
   40       0.11361185361321E-14    22.7127454826116
   41       0.11276519820716E-14    22.7127454826202
   42       0.11317183424878E-14    22.7127454826253
   43       0.11236007481770E-14    22.7127454826276
   44       0.11304065564684E-14    22.7127454826296
   45       0.11287791356431E-14    22.7127454826310
   46       0.11297028000133E-14    22.7127454826310
   47       0.11281236869666E-14    22.7127454826314
   48       0.11277254075548E-14    22.7127454826317
   49       0.11320327289847E-14    22.7127454826309
   50       0.11287655285563E-14    22.7127454826321
   51       0.11230503422400E-14    22.7127454826324
   52       0.11292089094944E-14    22.7127454826313
   53       0.11366728396408E-14    22.7127454826315
   54       0.11222618466968E-14    22.7127454826310
   55       0.11278193276516E-14    22.7127454826315
   56       0.11244624896030E-14    22.7127454826316
   57       0.11264508872685E-14    22.7127454826318
   58       0.11255583774760E-14    22.7127454826314
   59       0.11227129146723E-14    22.7127454826314
   60       0.11189480800173E-14    22.7127454826318
   61       0.11163241472678E-14    22.7127454826315
   62       0.11278839424218E-14    22.7127454826318
   63       0.11226804133008E-14    22.7127454826313
   64       0.11222456601361E-14    22.7127454826317
   65       0.11270879524310E-14    22.7127454826308
   66       0.11303771390006E-14    22.7127454826319
   67       0.11240101357287E-14    22.7127454826319
   68       0.11240278884391E-14    22.7127454826321
   69       0.11207748067718E-14    22.7127454826317
   70       0.11178755187571E-14    22.7127454826327
   71       0.11195935245649E-14    22.7127454826313
   72       0.11260715126337E-14    22.7127454826322
   73       0.11281677964997E-14    22.7127454826316
   74       0.11162340034815E-14    22.7127454826318
   75       0.11208709203921E-14    22.7127454826310
 Benchmark completed 
 VERIFICATION SUCCESSFUL 
 Zeta is     0.2271274548263E+02
 Error is    0.3128387698896E-15


 CG Benchmark Completed.
 Class           =                        B
 Size            =                    75000
 Iterations      =                       75
 Time in seconds =                    88.72
 Total processes =                        1
 Compiled procs  =                        1
 Mop/s total     =                   616.64
 Mop/s/process   =                   616.64
 Operation type  =           floating point
 Verification    =               SUCCESSFUL
 Version         =                      3.3
 Compile date    =              25 Dec 2014

 Compile options:
MPIF77       = mpif77
FLINK        = $(MPIF77)
FMPI_LIB     = -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lo...
FMPI_INC     = -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openm...
FFLAGS       = -O
FLINKFLAGS   = -O
RAND         = randi8


 Please send the results of this run to:

 NPB Development Team 
 Internet: npb@nas.nasa.gov

 If email is not available, send this to:

 MS T27A-1
 NASA Ames Research Center
 Moffett Field, CA  94035-1000

 Fax: 650-604-3957


Finish in 16:46:46--25/12/2014
-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-
-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-
Start in 17:03:13--25/12/2014


 NAS Parallel Benchmarks 3.3 -- CG Benchmark

 Size:      75000
 Iterations:    75
 Number of active processes:     1
 Number of nonzeroes per row:       13
 Eigenvalue shift: .600E+02

   iteration           ||r||                 zeta
    1       0.30354859861452E-12    59.9994751578754
    2       0.11186435488267E-14    21.7627846142536
    3       0.11312258511928E-14    22.2876617043224
    4       0.11222160585284E-14    22.5230738188346
    5       0.11244234177219E-14    22.6275390653892
    6       0.11330434819384E-14    22.6740259189533
    7       0.11334259623050E-14    22.6949056826251
    8       0.11374839313647E-14    22.7044023166872
    9       0.11424877443039E-14    22.7087834345620
   10       0.11329475190566E-14    22.7108351397177
   11       0.11337364093482E-14    22.7118107121341
   12       0.11379928308864E-14    22.7122816240971
   13       0.11369453681794E-14    22.7125122663243
   14       0.11430390337015E-14    22.7126268007594
   15       0.11400318886400E-14    22.7126844161819
   16       0.11352091331197E-14    22.7127137461755
   17       0.11350923439124E-14    22.7127288402000
   18       0.11475378864565E-14    22.7127366848296
   19       0.11366777929028E-14    22.7127407981217
   20       0.11274243312504E-14    22.7127429721364
   21       0.11353930792856E-14    22.7127441294025
   22       0.11299685800278E-14    22.7127447493900
   23       0.11296405041170E-14    22.7127450834533
   24       0.11381975597887E-14    22.7127452643881
   25       0.11328127301663E-14    22.7127453628451
   26       0.11367332658939E-14    22.7127454166517
   27       0.11283372178605E-14    22.7127454461696
   28       0.11384734158863E-14    22.7127454624211
   29       0.11394011989719E-14    22.7127454713974
   30       0.11354294067640E-14    22.7127454763703
   31       0.11412988029103E-14    22.7127454791343
   32       0.11358088407717E-14    22.7127454806740
   33       0.11263266152515E-14    22.7127454815316
   34       0.11275183080286E-14    22.7127454820131
   35       0.11328306951409E-14    22.7127454822840
   36       0.11357880314891E-14    22.7127454824349
   37       0.11332687790488E-14    22.7127454825202
   38       0.11324108818137E-14    22.7127454825684
   39       0.11365065523777E-14    22.7127454825967
   40       0.11361185361321E-14    22.7127454826116
   41       0.11276519820716E-14    22.7127454826202
   42       0.11317183424878E-14    22.7127454826253
   43       0.11236007481770E-14    22.7127454826276
   44       0.11304065564684E-14    22.7127454826296
   45       0.11287791356431E-14    22.7127454826310
   46       0.11297028000133E-14    22.7127454826310
   47       0.11281236869666E-14    22.7127454826314
   48       0.11277254075548E-14    22.7127454826317
   49       0.11320327289847E-14    22.7127454826309
   50       0.11287655285563E-14    22.7127454826321
   51       0.11230503422400E-14    22.7127454826324
   52       0.11292089094944E-14    22.7127454826313
   53       0.11366728396408E-14    22.7127454826315
   54       0.11222618466968E-14    22.7127454826310
   55       0.11278193276516E-14    22.7127454826315
   56       0.11244624896030E-14    22.7127454826316
   57       0.11264508872685E-14    22.7127454826318
   58       0.11255583774760E-14    22.7127454826314
   59       0.11227129146723E-14    22.7127454826314
   60       0.11189480800173E-14    22.7127454826318
   61       0.11163241472678E-14    22.7127454826315
   62       0.11278839424218E-14    22.7127454826318
   63       0.11226804133008E-14    22.7127454826313
   64       0.11222456601361E-14    22.7127454826317
   65       0.11270879524310E-14    22.7127454826308
   66       0.11303771390006E-14    22.7127454826319
   67       0.11240101357287E-14    22.7127454826319
   68       0.11240278884391E-14    22.7127454826321
   69       0.11207748067718E-14    22.7127454826317
   70       0.11178755187571E-14    22.7127454826327
   71       0.11195935245649E-14    22.7127454826313
   72       0.11260715126337E-14    22.7127454826322
   73       0.11281677964997E-14    22.7127454826316
   74       0.11162340034815E-14    22.7127454826318
   75       0.11208709203921E-14    22.7127454826310
 Benchmark completed 
 VERIFICATION SUCCESSFUL 
 Zeta is     0.2271274548263E+02
 Error is    0.3128387698896E-15


 CG Benchmark Completed.
 Class           =                        B
 Size            =                    75000
 Iterations      =                       75
 Time in seconds =                    87.47
 Total processes =                        1
 Compiled procs  =                        1
 Mop/s total     =                   625.43
 Mop/s/process   =                   625.43
 Operation type  =           floating point
 Verification    =               SUCCESSFUL
 Version         =                      3.3
 Compile date    =              25 Dec 2014

 Compile options:
MPIF77       = mpif77
FLINK        = $(MPIF77)
FMPI_LIB     = -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lo...
FMPI_INC     = -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openm...
FFLAGS       = -O
FLINKFLAGS   = -O
RAND         = randi8


 Please send the results of this run to:

 NPB Development Team 
 Internet: npb@nas.nasa.gov

 If email is not available, send this to:

     MS T27A-1
     NASA Ames Research Center
     Moffett Field, CA  94035-1000

     Fax: 650-604-3957


Finish in 17:04:43--25/12/2014
-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-
```

**tavg.dat**

```
88.3055
45.1482
37.7202
37.4035
53.777
```

**speedup.dat**

```
1
1.9559
2.34107
2.36089
1.64207
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one awk script that processes all the log files:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="=" }

lfname != FILENAME { lfname = FILENAME; split(FILENAME, a, "."); fnum=a[3] }

/Time in seconds/ { tsecs[fnum] += $2; tcnt[fnum]++ }
/Total processes/ { cp[fnum] = int($2) }

END {
    tavg1 = tsecs[1]/tcnt[1]
    for( k in tsecs ) {
        tavgk = tsecs[k]/tcnt[k]
        if( tavgk > 0 ) {
            print k OFS cp[k] OFS tavgk OFS tavg1/tavgk
        }
    }
}
```

If you put that in a file called `awk.script` and make it executable with `chmod +x awk.script` you can run it in bash like:

```
 ./awk.script cg.B.*.log
```

If you're using GNU awk, the output will be ordered( extra steps may be needed to ensure the output is ordered using other awk flavors ).

Where I generated a 2nd and 3rd file, the output is like:

```
1 1 88.095 1
2 2 68.095 1.29371
3 4 49.595 1.77629
```

where the unnamed columns are like: `file number`, `# processes`, `avg per file`, `speedup`.  You could get just the speedups by changing the print in the `END` block to be like `print tavg1/tavgk`.

Here's a breakdown of the script:

- Use a simpler field separator in `BEGIN`
- `lfname != FILENAME` - parse out file number from the filename as `fnum` but only when the `FILENAME` changes.
- `/Time in seconds/` - store the values in `tsecs` and `tcnt` arrays with an `fnum` key.  Use `int()` function to strip whitespace from processes value.
- `/Total processes/` - store the process in the `cp` array with an `fnum` key
- `END` - Calculate the average for fnum `1` as `tavg1`, loop through the keys in `tsecs` and calculate the average by `fnum` key as `tavgk`.  When `tavgk > 0` print the output as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You have figured out all the difficult parts already. You don't need the `tavg.dat` file at all. Create your `tavg(n)` function directly as a system call:

```
tavg(n) = system("awk 'BEGIN { FS = \"[ \\t]*=[ \\t]*\" }  \
/Time in seconds/ { s += $2; c++ } /Total processes/ { \
if (! CP) CP = $2 } END { print s/c }' cg.B.".n.".log")
```

And a `speedup(n)` function as

```
speedup(n)=tavg(n)/tavg(1)
```

Now you can `set print` to write to a file:

```
set print "speedup.dat"
do for [i=1:5] {
print speedup(i)
}
unset print
```